# Why Paxos is design in two phases

Tags: distributed-computing, paxos

Why Paxos requires two phases(`prepare/promise` + `accept/accepted`) instead of a single one? That is, using only `prepare/promise` portion, if the proposer has heard back from a majority of acceptors, that value is choose.

What is the problem, does it break safety or liveness?

Answer (score 3):

It breaks safety not to follow the full protocol.

Typical implementations of multi-paxos have a steady state mode where a stable leader streams `Accept` messages containing fresh values. Only when a problem occurs (leader crashes, stalls, or is partitioned by a network issue) does a new leader need to issue prepare messages to ensure saftey. A full description of this is in the [write-up of how TRex](https://simbo1905.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/transaction-log-replication-with-paxos/) an open source Paxos library implements Paxos.

Consider the following crash scenario which [TRex](https://github.com/trex-paxos/trex) would handle properly:

1. Nodes `A`, `B`, `C` with `A` leading
2. Client application sends `V1` to leader `A`
3. Node `A` is in steady state and so sends `accept(n, V1)` to nodes `B` and `C`. The network starts to fail though so only `B` sees the message and it replies with `accepted(n)`
4. Node `A` sees the response and has a majority `{A,B}` so it knows the value is fixed due to the safety proof of the protocol.
5. Node `A` attempts to broadcast the outcome to everyone just as it's server dies. Only the client application who issued the `V1` gets the message. Imagine that `V1` is a customer order and upon learning the order is fixed the client application debts the customer credit card.
6. Node `C` times out on the dead leader and attempts to lead. It never saw the value `V1`. It cannot arbitrarily choose any new value without rolling back the order `V1` but the customer has already been charged.
7. So Node `C` first issues a `prepare(n+1)` and node `B` responds with `promise(n+1, V1)`.
8. Node `C` then issues `accept(n+1, V1)` and as long as the remaining messages get through nodes `B` and `C` will learn the value `V1` was chosen.

Intuitively we can say that Node `C` has chosen to collaborate with the dead node `A` by choosing `A`'s value. So intuitively we can see why there must be two rounds. The first round is needed to discover whether there is any pending work to finish. The second round is used to fix the correct value to give consistency across all processes within the system.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely accurate, but you can think of the two phases as 1) copying the data, and then 2) committing the data. If the data is just copied to the other servers, those servers would have no idea if enough other servers have the data for it to be considered safe to serve. Thus there is a second phase to let the servers know that they can commit the data.

Paxos is a little more complex than that, which allows it to continue during failures of either phase. Part of the Paxos proof is that it is the *minimal* protocol for doing this completely. That is, other protocols do more work, either because they add more capabilities, or because they were poorly designed.

Comment: But the first phase of Paxos (prepare/promise) doesn't actually contain any data, so how is it related to your `1) copying the data`?

Comment: (answer my previous question): From reading https://martinfowler.com/articles/patterns-of-distributed-systems/paxos.html it seems like Paxos actually consist of 3 phases: prepare, accept, commit. The first two (prepare/accept) described in this post would be grouped together under your `1) copying the data` umbrella.

Comment: Paxos is definitely two phases (See the paper [Paxos Made Simple](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/paxos-made-simple/)). That third phase is an optional tack-on usually called the "learning phase". It is true that paxos is more accurately described as the two phases **Prepare-for-data** and **Here-is-data-Promise-you-wont-accept-earlier-data**; but the answer was tailored to the rough level of understanding as the OPs question.